# Javascript down count of var fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

i got a `button` in `html` that sets by `AJAX` a new tr
so i build a function(code below) to add it that works good but now i want a `counter` to look howmuch rows i have,
the up `counter` works, at the end of all rows i have a "trash" icon and by `click` the row disapears(that works fine too) but the down counter hava an `issue`
this is the `logic`

> 15
>   14
>   12
>   9
>   5
>   0
>   -6
>   -13
>   -21
>   -30
>   -40
>   -51
>   -63
>   -76
>   -90

"normaly this goes from 15 to 1"

```
var partcount = 1;
$('#AddName').click(function () {

    partcount ++;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("addParticipantToForm", "Events")",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.table tr:last').after(data);
        },

    });
    console.log(partcount);
    document.getElementById("partisipants-counter").innerHTML = partcount;
});
```

this is on one page

the second page is what execute every time the add button is pressed so i had to set the script for the trashcan here otherwise it wont work

```
@model Livework.Web.Ticketing.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel
<tr>
<td>
    naam
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(model  => model.thePartisipant.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new {       @class = "form-control" } })
</td>
<td>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default remove-name">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
</td>
</tr>

<script>

$('.remove-name').click(function () {

    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    partcount--;
    document.getElementById("partisipants-counter").innerHTML = partcount;
    console.log(partcount);
});
</script>
```

sorry for my bad english,
if there are any questions, let me know
thanks in advance

Comment: you have two declarations of partcount. If you remove one of them it should work.

Comment: unfortunately not sorry for that part in the code i was testing some things to make it word

Comment: @Jeroen why don't you put your `partcount` value inside hidden element and when you want to decrement the value - get the value from that hidden element and subtract it by 1

Comment: @RakeshShetty can you post an example in an answer for me
because its a nice salution but dont know how to use it #stillLearning

Comment: ok @Jeroen let me do that

Comment: @Jeroen I have posted a answer let me know it works for you or not

Answer (score 3):

Notice how the pattern goes "subtract one, then subtract two, then three, then four"...

This is because you are repeatedly binding the event handler and it is therefore getting called more and more times.

Instead, try delegating the event handler. Something like
`$(some container).click('.remove-name',function() {...});`

Comment: can you give an example by using the update from the question (i post know the complete file)

Answer (score 0):

As I told you can try like this : `you can put your partcount value inside hidden element and when you want to decrement the value - get the value from that hidden element and subtract it by 1`

Suppose you have hidden field :

```
<input type="hidden" id="count_hidden" value="1">
```

Jquery:

```
    $('#AddName').click(function () {

        var partcount = parseInt($('#count_hidden').val());
        partcount ++;
        $('#count_hidden').val(partcount)
        // You code//

    });


    $('.remove-name').click(function () {

      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
       var partcount = parseInt($('#count_hidden').val());
       partcount--;
       $('#count_hidden').val(partcount);

       //your code
   });
```

Comment: Why is this, a method that the user can hack around with in the browser console, any better than a variable (which if it's in a closure cannot be messed with without significant effort)?